# python hits out of index at if statement

Tags: python, indexoutofrangeexception

I try to extract information's out of this list (saved in a textfile):
People
にんげん、人間 – human (ningen)
じんるい、人類 – humanity (jinrui)
Occupations
いしゃ、医者 – doctor (isha)
かんごし、看護師 – nurse (kangoshi)

My goal is it, to get the translations in order. That I have in the end a list like this:

```
[{"People":["にんげん、人間 – human (ningen)", "じんるい、人類 – humanity (jinrui)"]},{"Occupations":["いしゃ、医者 – doctor (isha)", "かんごし、看護師 – nurse (kangoshi)"]}]
```

I don´t get why I´m getting the out of range error. I get the error when I set "**`count = line+1`**". When I remove the "`+ 1`", than the program functions. The program runs in the error when it hits "**`if "(" in edited_lines[count]:`**"

```
with open("data.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    raw_data = file.readlines()

edited_lines = [line.replace("\n", "") for line in raw_data]

finished_list = []
value_list = []
not_end = True


for line in range(0,len(edited_lines)-1):
    value_list.clear()
    if "(" not in edited_lines[line]:
        count = line+1
        while not_end:
            if "(" in edited_lines[count]:
                value_list.append(edited_lines[count])
                count += 1
            else:
                not_end = False
        new_dict = {edited_lines[line]:value_list}
        finished_list.append(new_dict)
        not_end = True
print(finished_list)
```

Here the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/Celvin/PycharmProjects/extractor/main.py", line 16, in
>
> if "(" in edited_lines[count]: IndexError: list index out of range

I thought I might run out of the index when I hit the end. So I was editing my code and tried to avoid the error:

```
with open("data.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    raw_data = file.readlines()

edited_lines = [line.replace("\n", "") for line in raw_data]

finished_list = []
value_list = []
not_end = True


for line in range(0,len(edited_lines)-1):
    value_list.clear()
    if "(" not in edited_lines[line]:
        count = line+1
        if count >= len(edited_lines): #!!!! added this if statement !!!!
            not_end = False
        while not_end:
            if "(" in edited_lines[count]:
                value_list.append(edited_lines[count])
                count += 1
            else:
                not_end = False
        new_dict = {edited_lines[line]:value_list}
        finished_list.append(new_dict)
        not_end = True
print(finished_list)
```

I did create an error and don´t get it.
I tried some different things too. But hadn´t success yet.

When I edit: "**count = line+1**" to "**count = line**", already some output how I need it.
[{'People': []}, {'Occupations': []}]

The code could contain further errors. Please don´t solve those for me. I really try to improve and learn out of my errors. I try only to write something here when I don´t understand something and already tried several things. Still a beginner. :)

Comment: And I know I would hit the next error with the attempt above. Just tried something to get the out of Index Error away! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
with open("data.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    raw_data = file.readlines()

edited_lines = [line.replace("\n", "") for line in raw_data]

finished_list = []

not_end = True


for line in range(0,len(edited_lines)-1):
    value_list = []
    if "(" not in edited_lines[line]:
        count = line+1
        while not_end and count < len(edited_lines):
            if "(" in edited_lines[count]:
                value_list.append(edited_lines[count])
                count += 1
            else:
                not_end = False
        new_dict = {edited_lines[line]: value_list}
        finished_list.append(new_dict)
        not_end = True
        
print(finished_list)
```

There were two issues in your code,

1. after you process the last line you increased `count` to value greater than length of `edited_lines`, then call `edited_lines[count]` this will cause *index out range error* so I put a check `count < len(edited_lines)` to stop this from happening.
2. you declared `value_list` as global variable. In the line `new_dict = {edited_lines[line]: value_list}` the values in `value_list` are not copied to the dictionary but its address is, when you later clear `value_list` the object inside `new_dict` still points to `value_list` and thus the values in the dictionary is also cleared. So I declared `value_list` inside the loop so that new *list*s are created for each loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This works great now and also thanks for the explanation!!! :)